# Can I add a new header in a circular doubly linked list?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I just had a assessment about data structures and algorithms. And my teacher said that it is impossible to add a new node before the header. I have checked everywhere (on the internet and books) and it all said that is was possible.

So now my question is, who is right here?

EDIT: Here is a picture of the situation, add the red arrow I need to insert a new node.

[image: http://imgur.com/F5qJ7JN]

Comment: your teacher is wrong, I don't know why she said so

Comment: It would appear that "adding a node before a header" is normally a meaningless proposition, but it's hard to tell without knowing what exactly you call "header' and "node", and ideally "before" too (yes, really).

Comment: It looks like you might be confusing "head" with "header". In a linked list, "head" is just a node that currently happens to be the first one. It is of course possible to add one before it. "Header" however is something different. Not every linked list implementation uses one. Google "linked list withba header".

Comment: atomicaly, eg in 1 non-interruptible operation, it is correct to say it is not possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a first element easily (in one step) even either to the usual linked list or double-linked one. You are right.

- The new element will get the pointer to the old first element.
- For double-linked list also the old first element gets back reference to the new element.
- The new element becomes the first one and is addressed as the list.

But be very soft and careful telling the teacher about his/her mistake. Maybe: "you meant inserting the last element in one step for the non-circular doubly linked list really, didn't you?" :-) I hope, you teacher is not the kind of person that gets easily offended hearing complex sentences.

As for the circular doubly linked list, you can insert both last or first element in one step. For the insert at head:

- A new element gets reference to the old first and the back reference to the last ( from the old head back reference)
- Old first changes its back reference to the new first
- Last changes its reference to the new first.
- Head (if you have one as a special something that has not data and is not a node) changes the reference to the new first. ***Edit*** According to your picture, you have not such thing.

You can also insert any element into any list, but it could take many steps moving from one element to another, for to reach the place.

***Edit*** 
Maybe, your teacher really meant that special reference that references the circular list from outside and has not its own data. It can exist for some special need. The very question of putting something **into the list before the header** has not sense at all - for the header does not belong to that part of the structure where the word **before** is defined. The element that is **before** the first element, is not outside the list, but it is the last element of the list.

That header, of course, can have something referencing it. The header is merely a reference, and it can have another "header of the header" and so on.

```
Big fleas have little fleas,
Upon their backs to bite 'em,
And little fleas have lesser fleas,
and so, ad infinitum.
```

And only an act of human will or some technical or religious limitation can forbide the possibility to reference a reference.

So, if the question (how to put something before the header) has sense, the word "before" for header must be interpreted as "referencing to", and we can put something before it. If "before" is defined for list nodes only, the question itself is senseless.

Comment: No, he's not. A header comes before anything else, by definition. The first record is entirely different from the header.

Comment: If by the header is meant the pure reference pointing to the first element, then it is not a node. And it is not really a part of list, so the talk of insert about it is simply senseless. We can't tell if the sentence is true or false if it has no sense. I hope, first element was meant.

Comment: I added a picture of the situation, to clear things up.

Comment: @Gangnus normally header is not a pointer but a special dummy node (sentinel) kept to simplify insertion and deletion. It's still not a regular node though because it contains no data and must always be the first one.

Comment: @n.m. What is "normally"? How an extra reference simplifies anything? The only use for it is the change of officially immutable variables. But such things should be solved as honest references/pointers, to be readable. Anyway, I had added a bit to the answer about that extra reference.

Comment: @Gangnus It's not a reference, it's a node. It simplifies everything by eliminating the special case of an empty list.

Comment: @n.m. In Java, f.e., thus you can have null list variable or list variable reverencing the list with null header. That is unnatural. Without that you can have null variable or list with empty list. 2 variants in both cases. Why the empty list is bad? It is very natural - you can have a list with no items in reality and this is good. In C++ the traditional way is even better - you have an empty list or non-empty list.

Comment: Google 'linked list with a header".

Comment: @n.m. When I dispute, and the opponent is very insistant, always google for the theme. (and of course I did this time, too). But an advice "google that" cannot work against arguments. There are too many references with many opinions. If you need good arguments, google for them, find them and put the reference AND the logical connection between the referenced material and your thought. Surely, I will consider them.

Comment: @n.m. Also, I would like to know better what is your thought exactly. For the subject of our dicussion had changed. Is it "a reference or a node" question? Can you insist that in all languages in all classes written for headed circular double list the header has the same type as list nodes? Because, if not, it is obviously not a node. And does not matter how many people say differently. Logic is above authorities.

Comment: I'm sorry I cannot answer extended questions in comments, comments are just not designed to handle it. If you have questions about how linked lists with header nodes work you are more than welcome to ask them normally on SO  (but make sure they are not duplicates first). If you do, pm me and I will try to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Linked Lists are dynamic meaning that there is no restriction on the size of it , and you can enter a node anywhere you desire, this is one of the many advantage of linked list. Your teacher might not have been talking about linked list may be circular queue otherwise she is wrong.